# Can't import HTML table into Google Sheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've been trying to import the "Detailed Standings" table from [this page](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standings.shtml) into a google sheet.

I have been using ImportHTML like this:

=ImportHTML("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standings.shtml", "table", 7)

The function always returns #N/A. If you do a number less than 7 it returns one of the other tables on the page. I tried inspecting the page source and the expanded settings do show up as having "table_number" = 7.

I tried tooling around with ImportXML as well, but had no luck. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: I was hoping to have the file automatically update daily with standings changes

Comment: It says you can get the table as a CSV or spreadsheet - share and more link!

Answer (score 0):

I also tried it, found this function in sheets doesn't import dynamically loading data.

if you main aim is to import data into your sheet then embed that sheet to your site then **solution i can give is**

1. Go with excel > Data > New Query > From other source > From Web > Paste link > Make connection > Select table you want and get data like
   [PIC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuCUD.jpg)
2. Click LOAD and get data and embed into site or do want you want to do. You can hide any column, etc from there. and import where you want and it can be interactive  if you want more follow this https://youtu.be/5ViZ7aOxF3I

[PIC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuDna.jpg)

If you want data in mobile, easy. Install EXCEL APP and log-in with same account after uploading on your cloud account, you will get it.

Thanks!